# Export environment variables in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Gradle supports multiple flavor builds for Android Applications. How can I export an environment variable which has different flavor values? For example, export FLAVOR with value "flavor1" when flavor1 is built and "flavor2" for flavor2 build.

```
android {
    ...
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            ...
        }

        flavor2 {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be using the environment variables?

Comment: See: https://heapandstack.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/environment-variables-in-gradle/

Comment: That link tells you that you can't set environment variables from Gradle. You might have better luck if you explain what you're trying to accomplish...wanting to set environment variables from your build script based on the flavor is pretty weird.

Answer (score 0):

This link http://inaka.net/blog/2014/12/22/create-separate-production-and-staging-builds-in-android/ may help you out.

If you have two productFlavors (Production and Staging, for instance)

You should create two different resource folders:

project/app/src/production/res/values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="root_url">http://production.service.com/api</string>
</resources>
```

project/app/src/staging/res/values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="root_url">http://staging.service.com/api</string>
</resources>
```

You should add this following code inside the android {}:

```
productFlavors {

    production {
        applicationId "com.inaka.app.production"
    }

    staging {
        applicationId "com.inaka.app.staging"
    }

}
```

It's a good idea to have different icons for different productFlavors, just add the icon inside each different resource folder.